# Calculating Pi with Taylor Method C++ and loop

Tags: c++

An approximate value of pi can be calculated using the series given below:

> pi = 4 * [ 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 … + ((-1)^n)/(2n + 1) ]

write a C++ program to calculate the approximate value of pi using this series. The program takes an input n that determines the number of terms in the approximation of the value of pi and outputs the approximation. Include a loop that allows the user to repeat this calculation for new values n until the user says she or he wants to end the program.

The expect result is:
Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):
1
The approximation is 4.00 using 1 term.
Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):
2
The approximation is 2.67 using 2 terms.
Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):
0

I can get the correct result now but I don't know how to Include a loop that allows the user to repeat this calculation for new values n until the user says she or he wants to end the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ int n; double pi, sum; 
do { 
     cout << "Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):" << endl;
     cin >> n;

if (n >0)
{

        double sum=1.0;
        int sign=-1;

    for (int i=1; i <=n; i++) {
    sum += sign/(2.0*i+1.0);
        sign=-sign;
    }
        pi=4.0*sum;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    cout << "The approximation is " << pi << " using "<< n << " terms" << endl;
}
} while(n>0);



    cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Stop declaring variables up front . Declare them right before/right at usage. You mix that.

Comment: maybe loop int i should equal 0. for (int i=0; i <=n; i++)

Comment: sum += (double)sign/(2.0*i+1.0);

Comment: `sign *=-1;` -> `sign=-sign` would be better

Comment: You are losing the first term.

Comment: I have updated my code. I don't know why my code cannot repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong initialization:

```
double sum=0.0;
int sign=1;
```

It should be

```
double sum = 1.0;
int sign = -1;
```

The loop is also wrong (has a typo?), it should be

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { /* please, notice "i < n" and "{"  */
    sum += sign / (2.0 * i + 1.0);
    sign = -sign; /* more readable, IMHO than  sign *=-1; */
}

pi = 4.0 * sum; /* you can well move it out of the loop */
```

**EDIT** if you want to *repeat calculation* a common practice is *extrating a function* (do not cram everything into single `main`):

```
double compute(int n) {
  if (n < 0) 
    return 0.0;

  double sum = 1.0;
  int sign = -1;

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
    sum += sign / (2.0 * i + 1.0);
    sign = -sign; /* more readable, IMHO than  sign *=-1; */
  }

  return 4.0 * sum;
}
```

**EDIT 2** the `main` function could be something like this:

```
int main() {
  int n = -1;

  /* quit on zero */
  while (n != 0) {
    cout << "Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to quit):" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    if (n > 0)
      cout << "The approximation is " << compute(n) << " using "<< n << " terms" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: when I input one, the expect result should be 4.00 not 2.66667.

Comment: @ZiWei Pan: then change `i <= n` to `i < n` in the loop condition (see my edit)

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko:  thx! how can I make the loop to repeat the calculation?

Comment: @ZiWei Pan: if you want to *repeat* calculation, *extract a function* (see my edit)

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko: I am not very understand your code. I have already updated my code and my question. I just not sure how to use it in my code.

Comment: @ZiWei Pan: I see, you're looking for `main` function; I suggest looping `while (restart == 'Y')` (see my edit)

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko:  I submit my code to test, and it has some errors : [link] (https://submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/200330). May be you can have a look. I also update my code latest.

Comment: OK! I got it. But for this error, how can I fix it?  [link] (https://submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/200340)

Answer (score 0):

The alternating sign must be part of your loop. Include it into the loop body by using a compound statement:

```
for (int i=1; i <=n; i++) {
  sum += sign/(2.0*i+1.0);
  sign *=-1;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. I don't know why my code cannot repeat.